# Как записать byte[] в файл и запустить установку

Tags: java, android

У меня есть отправка файла с телефона а точнее файл конвертируется в byte и эти byte отправляются на часы.

```
public void onSend(View view) {
    File file = new File("wearOs.apk");

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Collection<String> nodes = getNodes();
            LOGD(TAG, "Nodes: " + nodes.size());
            for (String node : nodes) {
                Task<ChannelClient.Channel> channelTask = Wearable.getChannelClient(getApplicationContext()).openChannel(node, CHANNEL_MSG);
                channelTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ChannelClient.Channel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ChannelClient.Channel channel) {
                        LOGD(TAG, "onSuccess " + channel.getNodeId());
                        Task<OutputStream> outputStreamTask = Wearable.getChannelClient(getApplicationContext()).getOutputStream(channel);
                        outputStreamTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<OutputStream>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(OutputStream outputStream) {
                                LOGD(TAG, "output stream onSuccess");
                                try {
                                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(file));
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                                    int len;
                                    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
                                        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);

                                    outputStream.write(byteBuffer.toByteArray());
                                    outputStream.flush();
                                    outputStream.close();
                                    inputStream.close();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Не могу разобраться как мне на часах получить эти byte, записать их в файл с тем же названием и расширением и запустить установку apk файла?

Пробовал таким образом но нечего не получается

```
try {
                                File file = new File("wearOs.apk");

                                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                int read;
                                byte[] data = new byte[1024];

                                while ((read = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "data length " + read); /** use Log.e to force print, if Log.d does not work */
                                    buffer.write(data, 0, read);

                                    buffer.flush();
                                    byte[] byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();

                                    try (FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("wearOs.apk")){
                                        fileOuputStream.write(byteArray);
                                    }

                                }
                                Log.d(TAG, "reading: " + file);
                                final File finalFile = file;
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE).putExtra("wearOs.apk", finalFile);
                                    }
                                });

                                inputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                Wearable.getChannelClient(getApplicationContext()).close(channel);
                            }
```

Comment: Для начала не стоит пустое имя файлу задавать: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#File(java.lang.String)

Comment: Создал apk файл в той же директории что и на телефоне `File file = new File("wearOs.apk");` но нечего не происходит

Comment: `startActivity(intent);` - не забыл?